# Java Consumer. Extract input the input argument

Tags: java, oop, hashmap, consumer

In the following piece of code, I am using Java Consumer and I want to extract the value of the input argument, ***event*** to be used elsewhere in my code. Can that be done and if so how?

```
Consumer<Map<String, Object>> consumer = event -> System.out.println(event);
```

Comment: You can't *extract* from a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html), since the entire point of a consumer is to consume/absorb the values. If you want to extract values, the object needs to be a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html).

Comment: Or maybe you can use an [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) to consume the input and then return it to re use it again using function composition

Comment: Is it possible to resolve the consumer line into a variable to be used elsewhere?

Comment: You can expand the consumer body and use `event` there:
`Consumer<Map<String, Object>> consumer = event -> { System.out.println(event); doSomething(event); };`